# Visual Studio Code Not Recognizing findent Installation for Modern Fortran Extension Despite Correct Python Interpreter and PATH Configuration

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, environment-variables, fortran

I am working with the [Modern Fortran extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fortran-lang.linter-gfortran) in Visual Studio Code on Windows and keep encountering a persistent issue. Despite having correctly installed `findent`, `fortran-language-server`, and `fprettify` using a specific Python interpreter and updating my user `settings.json` in VS Code to include the necessary path, the extension does not seem to recognize `findent`, and I continue to receive the following message:

> Installing findent.exe through pip with --user option
> Source: Modern Fortran

[image]

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Selected the Python interpreter inside Visual Studio Code explicitly set to `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe`.
2. Installed the required packages with the commands:

   - `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe install findent --user`
   - `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe install fortran-language-server`
   - `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe install fprettify`
3. Added the following to my `settings.json` to ensure the VS Code terminal recognizes the scripts installed by `pip`:

   ```json
   "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
       "PATH": "${env:PATH};C:\\Users\\<userName>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Scripts;"
   }
   ```

Despite these configurations, indentation, beautifying, and prettifying for Fortran code do not work, and I keep seeing the prompt to install `findent`.

Has anyone faced a similar issue, or can you offer insight into what might be missing or incorrectly configured in my setup?

Answer (score 1):

In Modern Fortran, Windows autodetection of Python packages is a bit problematic at the moment, see [PR](https://github.com/fortran-lang/vscode-fortran-support/pull/824) and [GSoC project](https://github.com/fortran-lang/webpage/wiki/GSoC-2024-Project-ideas#python-environment-manager-vscode-fortran-support).

### Solution 1: quick

That being said for users that **don't** have the default pip location added to their `PATH`, a very low effort, platform independent, workaround is shown in this [comment](https://github.com/fortran-lang/vscode-fortran-support/issues/957#issuecomment-1726741195).

### Solution 2: long

If you want to get it working **without** the aforementioned workaround, you will have to:

- Start by installing the pre-Release of Modern Fortran
- To make debugging easier set the option `fortran.logging.level` to DEBUG, your VS Code OUTPUT pane should now contain all sorts of useful messages under Modern Fortran.

#### Formatting

- In step 2. when installing `fprettify` copy the directory where `pip` installs the `.exe`
- use it to set the Modern Fortran option `fortran.formatting.path` equal to that directory (without `fprettiffy.exe`, just the full directory).

#### Language server

- You must use `fortls` not `fortran-language-server`. Install via `pip install fortls --pre` to install the pre-release (highly recommended).
- Similarly to the formatter, copy the directory where pip install the `fortls.exe`
- Set Modern Fortran option `fortran.fortls.path` to install directory + fortls.exe in your VS Code settings (quite annoying that the formatter and this option require slightly different inputs, we will fix in a future release).

The debug logs in the OUTPUT pane will be extremely helpful when you are trying to setup your machine.

---

As a side note, I think Step 3. should not work for any VS Code extension, unless they have gone out of their way to implement such functionality. The VS Code extension environment knows nothing about the VS Code terminal `PATH`. I think the terminal inherits from the VS Code environment, not the other way around.